# Why does my male pitbull drink my female's pee (while she's in heat)?

Tags: dogs, behavior

I am an owner of two full white rednose pitbulls (male named Rocky and female named Roxie). They're brother and sister.

Roxie is 11 months old and is a few days into her first heat. When she pees she also bleeds.

Rocky, who is also 11 months, always follows her around and drinks her pee and blood. I think he's sick. There's been nights where he cries before going to bed. What should I do? This has never happened to me.

Answer (score 6):

This is normal behavior for a male dog when a female dog is in heat.  Dogs (and many other animals) have a Jacobson's organ on the roof of their mouths they use for "tasting" the air, like an additional way to smell.  The Jacobson's organ is used to smell pheromones that a female gives off while she is in estrus.  It is also common, when the female is going into estrus, for the males to taste their urine, in order to better smell her pheromones with the Jacobson's organ.  Since your dogs are brother and sister, if the male is also not neutered, please make sure to keep them apart while the female is in estrus.  Dogs will inbreed if given the opportunity.